# jQuery Object Not able to find the class

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why but jQuery find function is not able to find the class using the class name.

Here is the result from Visual Studio immediate window which shows that there is a class called TBLCONTENTS but when searched using the find method it returns nothing.

```
optionRows[0].className
"TBLCONTENTS"

optionRows.find(".TBLCONTENTS")
{...}
    context: {object}
    jquery: "1.7.1"
    length: 0
    prevObject: {...}
    selector: ".TBLCONTENTS"
```

Can I remove rows based on the filter:

```
$(optionRows).filter(".TBLCONTENTS").not(":first").remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `find` looks at the descendants. You might want `filter` instead.

Comment: Oh of course you are right! I was pulling my hair out on this one :D

Comment: for some reason it does not remove the rows

Answer (score 1):

from [the documentation for find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get **the descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector [...]

so if the parent itself is what you're looking for, `find()` is the wrong way to go - use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.